# Unable to open Windows Disk partitions in solaris 11

Tags: unix, partitioning, solaris

The NTFS Windows HD partitions are not appearing in solaris file system, which was not the case when I used Ubuntu. Every single file on my HD was exposed to me when I was in Ubuntu.

I have already tried to find the solution in the internet. Tried to solve it with the  of [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/mounting_windows_ntfs_on_open) But had no success. The download links given for both FSWpart and FSWfsmisc is not working (giving a 404). I installed something called ntfs-g drive but I think I am not using it correctly as most of the time I am copying and pasting commands because I do not have sufficient knowledge to write them myself.

Edit  :

Yeah I have tried that link too. But when I click on that download link, another webpage appears which displays a .png image stating that the named file can not be displayed because it contains errors.

And for the ntfs -3g commands I used. Sorry I should have mentioned them earlier. Here is what i have done

```
$ ntfs-3g /dev/dsk /mnt/c7d0p0
Error opening '/dev/dsk': Is a directory
Failed to mount '/dev/dsk': Is a directory
```

I have followed these commands from the README file came with the software package.
There was another command type which I couldn't use

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

for example.

WHen I tried it like this-

```
$ mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/dsk/c7d0p0
mount: illegal option -- t
Usage:
mount [-v | -p]
mount [-F FSType] [-V] [current_options] [-o specific_options]
{special | mount_point}
mount [-F FSType] [-V] [current_options] [-o specific_options]
special mount_point
mount -a [-F FSType ] [-V] [current_options] [-o specific_options]
[mount_point ...]
```

As you can clearly see I am unable(due to my insufficient knowledge of unix) to perform the second command successfully.

Comment: Follow these instructions to get the file.  This process is well documented.  http://aminsblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/mount-ntfs-in-solaris-11/

Comment: Please show us the commands you tried. We can't help if we don't know what you've done. How are you attempting to mount the NTFS partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your syntax all munged.

What you need is something like this:

```
mount -F ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

Where /dev/sda1 should be replaced with the path to your disk, and /mnt/windows is an empty directory to be used as the mountpoint.

Specifying the FS type may not be necessary, but note that the switch is -F, not -t.